# Storing xml file in svn

Tags: xml, svn

I am keeping .xml files under svn. I would like to include svn info into comment section similar to c++: `'// $Id$'`

I tried `'<!-- $Id$ -->'` it was not recognized by svn as a keyword. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in the XML file (you can type the `$Id$` keyword in any file).

But you have to tell Subversion that you want the keyword substitution on the particular file.

For example for the `Id` and `Author` keywords

```
svn propset svn:keywords 'Id Author' yourfile.xml
```

You can also instruct Subversion to enable the substitution with auto-props.

In your Subversion client config file (e.g., `~/.subversion/config`) in the `[miscellany]` section, set `enable-auto-props` to true.

And in the `[auto-props]` section (probably need to create it) you can define the rules.

For example:

```
[miscellany]
enable-auto-props = true

[auto-props]
*.xml = svn:keywords=Id
```

Answer (score 0):

`<!-- $Id$ -->` is fine, the issue is that Subversion only replaces keywords in files that you've specifically tagged with the `svn:keywords` property.  If you do

```
svn propset svn:keywords Id file.xml
```

then it'll update the comment when you next commit.

To make this the default for all newly-added `.xml` files you would need to edit the "auto-props" definitions in your subversion configuration, or (if you're on subversion 1.8.x or later) set the `svn:auto-props` property on one of the ancestor directories up the tree.  The [Subversion book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto) has the full details.